# Concentric shells of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

What exactly happens when two concentric shells, of different radii carrying different charge say $q$ and $Q$, are connected through a conducting wire?

Will the potential of both the shells be the same?
Won't all the charges gather around the bigger shell?

Comment: Any persistent potential difference will make the charges flow forever.

Comment: yes,but since they are connected by a wire,there potential should be same i think?

Comment: My bad, the answer to the first question is yes and the second question is no. You need to calculate the potentials of a spherical charged sphere using the formula of capacitance and then equate them to find out the ratio of charges shared between them

Comment: okay so then the charge on my smaller shell will be become zero,and all charges will gather around the bigger one

Comment: I updated my comment. Sorry, I have been out of touch with basic electrodynamics for a long time that's why it took me some time to realise the exact question. Interesting question though. Tell me if you need a formal answer, I'll post it.

Comment: okay so i cannot assume charges would jut flow based on size and the property tha charges reside on the surface .yes, thank you

Comment: Charges flow only due to potential difference. Most advanced problems in electrostatics are solved assuming there are no potential difference between points connected by a conductor in an ad hoc manner. Because otherwise it wouldn't be an electrostatics problem. Your intuition that charges reside on the outer surface is a consequence of the same in the special case when the conductor is a charged solid sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the potential of both the shells be the same?

Yes. This is the definition of an ideal conductor.

> Won't all the charges gather around the bigger shell?

Yes, they will. Contrary to what I said in the comments, they will gather up on the surface of the bigger sphere. To show this, consider the electric flux through a spherical surface between the two spheres. This is given by:$$\int\vec E\cdot d\vec A=q_{enc}$$where the enclosed charge $q_{enc}$ is the charge on the inner sphere. Now, due to the spherical symmetry of the charge distribution, the electric field has to point radially outwards and have the same value on the sphere. This gives $$|\vec E(r)|=\frac{q_{enc}}{4\pi r^2}.$$
Now, $$\Delta V=\frac{q_{enc}}{4\pi}\int _r ^R\frac{dr}{r^2}=\frac{q_{enc}}{4\pi}(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{R}).$$

Now, *since $\Delta V=0$ and $r\neq R$*, $q_{enc}=0$. So, all charges end up on the outer shell.

**Note**:

1. I employed the same principle as in my comments to conclude it: calculate $\Delta V$ for the configuration and then set it to zero. My mistakes were to assume non-applicable formulas of $\Delta V$.
2. You were right in your intuition.
3. This process of connecting the two spheres  doesn't conserve energy. The field outside the outer sphere is not changed by this action but inside it drops to zero instantly. So, $\int E(x)^2 d^3x$ is not the same before and after the charge rearrangement. Which it should, because,  the energy conservation equation in this case is $\frac{dU}{dt}=-\vec E\cdot \vec j$ and according to the configuration, $\vec j$ must have a radially outward component, along the direction of $\vec E$.